# For loop works but is not summing in python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

My input is a list of words. Such as ["love", "sky", "NOT_movie"], [ "NOT_house", "NOT_CAR"]. And what I would like to do is, for this list of words, if the word starts with "NOT_" I score it with -1 and if it is not a word starting with "NOT_" I score it with +1. My expected result is a list with the score for each of the sets on my initial list

I have the following code that is supposed to calculate the scores by adding +=1 according to the following condition

```
 for i in range(len(temp2)):
        for j in range(len(temp2[i])):
            if temp2[i][j] in lex2:
                if "NOT_" in list_test_data2[i][j]:
                    value = lex2[str(temp2[i][j])] * (-1)
                    print(value)
                else: 
                    value = lex2[str(temp2[i][j])]
                    print(value)
                    
                    if value == 1 :
                        count_pos+=1
                    elif value == -1 :
                           count_neg+=1
            
        list_scores2.append((count_pos - count_neg)/(count_pos + count_neg + 2))
        count_pos=0
        count_neg=0
```

However, when printing list_scores2 I have the following output

```
print(list_scores2)
```

> [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you show us the input data? And also what you're trying to achieve with the code as wel (output)

Comment: The indentation looks broken. You should provide a [mre] that we can run. I.e. you should provide some hard-coded data for us to run the example.

Comment: @VedankPande my input is a list of words.  Such as ["love", "sky", "NOT_movie"], [ "NOT_house", "NOT_CAR"]. And what I would like to do is, for this list of words, if the word starts with "NOT_" I score it with -1 and if it is not a word starting with "NOT_" I score it with +1. My expected result is a list with the score for each of the sets on my initial list.

Comment: Ok, and that list is `temp2`? What about `lex2` and `list_test_data2`?

Comment: Sample input/output maybe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the most pythonic or efficient way to do it, but it works:

```
ip = [["love", "sky", "NOT_movie"], [ "NOT_house", "NOT_CAR"]]

res = []

for sublist in ip: #note how the list is iterated through - instead of using range()
    score_list = []  #this holds score for each word in a sublist
    for word in sublist:
        if word.startswith("NOT_"):
            score_list.append(-1)
        else:
            score_list.append(1)
    res.append(sum(score_list)) #append total score for that sublist into res list

print(res)
```

output:

```
[1,-2]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension to loop first over the lists and then again over each list.

```
word_lists = [["love", "sky", "NOT_movie"], ["NOT_house", "NOT_CAR"]]

[
    sum([-1 if word.startswith("NOT_") else 1 for word in word_list])
    for word_list in word_lists
]
```

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas.

1. First, check your first if statement: `if temp2[i][j] in lex2:` I'm not sure what's in lex2, but if that statement is never true, you'd probably get the output you're describing. So, first check if the code is ever getting inside that if statement. If it isn't, then this is the issue.
2. if `if "NOT_" in list_test_data2[i][j]:` is always true, then it would also produce that output you're getting. If this is the case, then your count variables will never change as it only exists in the else statement.
3. `value` is never +1 or -1. That would mean the output would always be zero. Maybe check on the type of value being returned. "-1" isn't the same as -1.

Another thing to consider, is there are other ways to structure this that may be helpful in doing this more efficiently and descriptively so it's easier to debug. I've seen a few good suggestions above, but here are a few tips:

- I'd avoid naming variables "temp" as they make it more difficult to understand what your code is doing.
- Loop over the words instead of the indexes. Even better if you can use built-in functions to make your code smaller. There are probably better versions than this, but I think this may do roughly the same thing as what you have:

  ```
  for wordlist in temp2:
    count_pos = sum("NOT_" in word for word in wordlist)    
    count_neg = len(wordlist) - count_pos
    list_scores2.append((count_pos - count_neg)/(count_pos + count_neg + 2))
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple one liner might just do the trick

```
>>>[sum(1 if word.startswith("NOT_") else -1 for word in subl) for subl in [["love", "sky", "NOT_movie"], ["NOT_house", "NOT_CAR"]]]

[-1, 2]
```